Proof in measure theory
I  have found excellent proof about changing variables in polar coordinate
This is the problem
Let $S^{n-1}=\left\{x \in R^2:|x|=1\right\}$ and for any Borel set $E \in S^{n-1}$ set $E *=\{r \theta: 0<r<1, \theta \in E\}$. Define the measure $\sigma$ on $S^{n-1}$ by $\sigma(E)=n|E *|$.
With this definition the surface area $\omega_{n-1}$ of the sphere in $R^n$ satisfies $\omega_{n-1}=n \gamma_n=\frac{2 \pi^{n / 2}}{\Gamma(n / 2)}$, where $\gamma_n$ is the volume of the unit ball in $R^n$. Prove that for all non-negative Borel functions $f$ on $R^n$,
$$
\int_{R^n} f(x) d x=\int_0^{\infty} r^{n-1}\left(\int_{S^{n-1}} f(r \theta) d \sigma(\theta)\right) d r .
$$
this is the solution, but I didn't catch what is underlined

Can someone prove it? Thanks
EDIT  I was also proving another apprach. I thought that if $A$ is an open subset of $S_(n−1)$ if I call E be the set of all ru with $r_1 < r < r_2$ , $u \in  A$, I verified  that the
formula holds for the characteristic function of E and now i wanted to pass from these
to characteristic functions of Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^k$. but I don't know how to prove in detail... I only have the idea

How does your text define the surface measure $\sigma$?

The measure $d\sigma$ is the surface measure on $S^{n - 1}$. Surface measure is defined on any surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The proof of your claim is a straightforward computation. See page 123 of https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf

@Kakashi I have edited teh question a little bit .Can you please help me?

@Dsrksidemath Ad-hoc definitions are, in my opinion, a bad way to proceed. The best way is to use the already well established definition of surface measure and apply it here.

To be honest, that is one of the results that everyone uses but (almost) no one knows how to prove it without checking a reference. The main idea is to use the spherical coordinates which is $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto (r,\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_{n-1})$ given by
$$
x_1=r\cos(\varphi_1),
$$
$$
x_2=r\sin(\varphi_1)\cos(\varphi_2),
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
$$
x_{n-1}=r\sin(\varphi_1)\cdots\sin(\varphi_{n-2})\cos(\varphi_{n-1}),
$$
$$
x_{n}=r\sin(\varphi_1)\cdots\sin(\varphi_{n-2})\sin(\varphi_{n-1}).
$$
Evaluating the Jacobian, we have
$$
|J|=r^{n-1}\sin^{n-1}(\varphi_1)\cdots\sin^2(\varphi_{n-3})\sin(\varphi_{n-2}).
$$
Then, using the change of variables formula (note that $r\in(0,\infty)$, $\varphi_1,\ldots\varphi_{n-2}\in(0,\pi)$, and $\varphi_{n-1}\in(0,2\pi)$),
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n}f(x)\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\pi\cdots\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}f(r\theta)r^{n-1}\sin^{n-1}(\varphi_1)\cdots\sin(\varphi_{n-2})\mathrm dr\mathrm d\varphi_1\cdots\mathrm d\varphi_{n-1},
$$
where
$$
\theta=\dfrac{x}{r}=\left(\cos(\varphi_1),\sin(\varphi_1)\cos(\varphi_2),\ldots \sinh(\varphi_1)\cdots\sin(\varphi_{n-1})\right).
$$
Therefore, since the the measure of $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ can be seen as
$$
\mathrm d\sigma(\theta)=\sin^{n-1}(\varphi_1)\cdots\sin(\varphi_{n-2})\mathrm d\varphi_1\cdots\mathrm d\varphi_{n-1},
$$
we conclude the desired equation
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n}f(x)\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty\int_{\mathbb S^{n-1}}r^{n-1}f(r\theta)\mathrm d\sigma(\theta)\mathrm dr.
$$

really thanks , I was also proving another apprach can you help me ? I thought that if $A$ is an open subset of $S_(n−1)$ if I call E be the set of all ru with $r_1 < r < r_2$ , $u \in  A$, I verified  that the
formula holds for the characteristic function of E and now i wanted to pass from these
to characteristic functions of Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^k$. but I don't know how to prove in detail... I only have the idea
